# Javascript File object missing from body

Tags: node.js, express, file, axios

I have a valid object file with data in it when I do the request on the front end.
But when I receive the body on the express backend the file object is empty.

```
 let body = {
            metadata: {
            date: date, 
            location: location, 
            description: description, 
            file: file
            }
        }


    const headers = {'body': JSON.stringify(body)}

  
    axios.get('/api/xummMint', {headers}).then( (res) => { 


      console.log("xumm data coming");
      console.log(res)

      setData({xummData: res});

    })
```

when I console.log(req.headers.body) I receive an empty file object even though the file had data on the frontend:

```
{"metadata":{"date":"2022-12-30","location":"asf","description":"asdf","file":{}}}
```

I tried using fetch and adding content-Type: application/json but still same results. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that you meant to send this as a POST request with a JSON body, not as a GET request with a header called "body"

```js
axios.post(
    '/api/xummMint',
    body, 
    {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}
).then(res => {
    console.log("xumm data coming");
    console.log(res);

    setData({xummData: res});
});
```

Comment: i'm getting undefined now when I try to see it on the backend ( console.log(req.body) )